# Container in Row() Are not Working in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and I was making some random blocks to practice my known knowledge.
I was trying to make three column where the last column will contain two row and all of them are in one column and they are in one Card widget.My Columns are working perfectly but My Containers of the rows are not working.
As a newbie, I Failed to understand where and what I am missing or my wrong-doing.

I was trying to make this view
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCBFw.png)

Here is my Code -- >

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('Button'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('Button'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ), //Checking if Text button is working or Not
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide the text "Button" as an child to Container, not with some separate Widget like TextButton . Also you haven't provided any width to Container that's why you would not see anything .You can do something as below:

```
              Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: Center(child: const Text('Button')),
                  height: 100,

                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Center(
                      child: const Text('Button',
                   style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks, The Container Now working  (after adding width as your advise).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the yellow and black containers with an `Expanded` widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 100,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```